# why cant you retrieve text from EditText widget in Android?

Tags: android, android-widget, widget, android-edittext, android-studio

why cant you retrieve text from EditText widget in Android? even on android developer guide they game an example as if you can 
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html 
Is they actually ANY way at all? Becasue I want to create a simple login dialog box and the programs has to check the logins the user has typed how can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how you can get the text from an EditText in a custom dialog.

```
  AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
  // Get the layout inflater, and inflate the dialog's view (which contains the EditText)
  LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
  View dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_signin, null);

  // Keep a reference to the EditText you can use when the user clicks the button
  final EditText editText = (EditText) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.my_edit_text);

  // Inflate and set the layout for the dialog
  builder.setView(dialogView)
      // Add action buttons
      .setPositiveButton(R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
          // The user clicked 'ok' or 'sign-in' - now you can get the text from the EditText
          String textFromEditText = editText.getText().toString();
        }
      });
  // Build & show the dialog
  builder.create().show();
```

Answer (score 0):

> why cant you retrieve text from EditText widget in Android?

Call `getText()` on the `EditText` widget to retrieve the text. It will come back as a `CharSequence`, technically an instance of `SpannedString` I think. Call `toString()` on that to get a plain string, if you are not expecting any formatting.

Comment: I've tried that and it works but it doesnt work on EditText widgets that are inside a Dialog blox

Comment: @user3050399: Sure it does. The fact that you weren't able to make it work means you're probably something wrong (i.e. call it at the incorrect point in time). That's usually why providing some code in a question is considered to be good practice. It'll enable us to potentially point out any mistakes/misunderstandings. Without that, it's pretty much shooting in the dark.